# Launch a java application with parameters from Windows cmd?

Tags: java, windows, parameters, cmd

I am sorry but I don't speak English very well.. :)

When I want launch a java project from windows cmd I do :

`javac main.java` (main = name of my file)

then : `java main`

But if I use parameters, how can I do?

I tried : `java main parameters` but it is not good.

Have you an idea?

Thank you very much for your help :)

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ENJTi.png)

**Here there is the code :**

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;

import elements.*;

public class Main
{
    public static void main(String[] parameters)
    {
        try
        {
            String nameFile = parameters[0];
            FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(new File(nameFile));
            Processing processing = new Processing();
            processing.read(fileInputStream);
            try 
            {
                fileInputStream.close();
            } 
            catch (IOException exception) 
            {
                System.out.println("Une erreur s'est produite lors de la fermeture de l'InputStream");
            }
        }
        catch(FileNotFoundException exeption)
        {
            System.out.println("Le nom de fichier placé en paramètre est incorrect");
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is the line 14 : `String nameFile = parameters[0];`

Comment: you should be able to read command line parameters by referencing the args[] array. can you share the code that you are trying to run and the exact command?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so looks like you are able to read the parameters but you are getting a FileNotFoundException. The way that you are reading the file, the exercice4.txt should be present in your src folder, other wise your current code will not be able to read it. either pass the full path of the file or update your code

Comment: Thank you very much !! All is good now :)

I placed my file in src folder :)

Comment: glad i could help :) please accept the answer when you get a chance

Answer (score 0):

Well, the code seems correct, but for sure it will not work because the file is not in the directory in which you run the `java blah blah` command. Try running

```
java Main ..\exercice4.txt
```

By the way, this kind of problems is usually easy to debug with a few print statements, e.g:

```
String nameFile = parameters[0];
System.out.println("Trying to open file "+nameFile);
FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(new File(nameFile));
```

Also when there is an exception it is useful to display the exception stack trace, e.g:

```
catch(FileNotFoundException exeption)
{
    System.out.println("Le nom de fichier placé en paramètre est incorrect");
    exeption.printStackTrace();
}
```